# Is there any way to parallel such functions with openMP?

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a code line that I think I can parallel somehow, e.g:

```
int f1(a,b){
.....
}
int f2(a1,b1,a2,b2){
    //here we are calling f1 function twice
    int k = f1(a1,b1) * f1(a2,b2);
    .....
    return k;
}
int main(){

    int result = f2(.....);
}
```

Is there any way how to use "#pragma omp parallel" to call these f1 functions at the same time? And then of course put result in "k".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that `f1()` has no bad side effects, e.g., doesn't change some global state without properly locking it, you may simply split the expression in two and use the `sections` construct to run each part in parallel:

```cpp
int f2(a1, b1, a2, b2) {
   int k11, k22;

   #pragma omp parallel sections
   {
      #pragma omp section
      k11 = f1(a1, b1);

      #pragma omp section
      k22 = f1(a2, b2);
   }

   int k = k11 * k22;
   ...
   return k;
}
```